# Verb-past + 中でも

Tags: grammar

> 「**俺の見た中でも**最悪の、極めつきの大マグルの家で育てられるなんて、おまえさんも不運だったなあ」
> It's your bad luck to be raised in the house of a the worst great muggle *I've ever seen*.

I cannot find the pattern "verb-past + 中でも" discussed anywhere. I'm guessing 俺の見た中でも is literally "among those I have seen ...". Is that correct?

Is this a common pattern? Can it be used with other verbs? Could you give some examples please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm guessing 俺の見た中でも is literally "among those I have seen ...". Is that correct?

Yes, that's correct. The 中 means:

> なか【中】
> ５ 限られた範囲に含まれる部分。一定のグループや集団の範囲のうち。「人込みの―を急ぐ」「仲間の―でいちばん若い」「予算の―でまかなう」
> ([デジタル大辞泉](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8B/#jn-162820))

> Is this a common pattern? Can it be used with other verbs? Could you give some examples please?

I think it's pretty common. Examples:

> 「私が**知っている中で**最も安い店」
> 「今まで**食べた中で**一番おいしかったです。」
> 「この棚に**ある中**から選んでください。」